# Add GA Experiments to .php for specific homepages for an a/b test

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-experiments

I have been really struggling with something, wondered if anyone could help.

I am trying to run a Google Experiment to A/B test my homepage to a variation homepage that i've already created in Wordpress.

I need to add the Google analytics code to the  of the two homepage's, i think i need a php code to target the two homepage's.

I previously used (many) Wordpress plugin's and each plugin wouldn't let me specify where the code hit, it just ran the code across the whole site, so I was getting the variation homepage on every link i clicked through on my site.

This is my header.php and i think i need a php code to specify the two homepage's to attack with the Google experiment code?

```
<header class="banner container" role="banner">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <a class="brand" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
      <nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
        <?php
          if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
            wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav nav-pills'));
          endif;
        ?>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Matt (SEO and CRO intern)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is a `.php` code to specify the two homepage's ... ? Some detail would be great, I think.

Comment: I need to add GA (Google analytics) code to target just two specific pages (http://joosr.com, and http://joosr.com/home) From what I’ve read from searching how to do this, you need to add some PHP code in the header to add the GA to the two specific pages. All the plugins that add GA seem to add it to every single page, which isn’t what I want. Sorry if I sound uneducated in my question and response, quite new to this! @Dilettant

Comment: If you want to do a Google experiment you should add the experiment only to one page (the original). The code selects a variation and redirects to the selected variation; if you do the same on the variation page visitors will not get the same variation for recurring visits (which would invalidate your test) and might get caught in serial redirects.

Comment: Thanks Eike, do you know how i can add the experiment code to my home page in the header.php code i provided in my original question? I've built my homepage through wordpress and metabox blocks so when i edit the homepage i have no-where (in code) to add the experiment @EikePierstorff

Comment: I think i have resolved the problem now, thanks for your help Eike. I have put the code into just the original homepage and its working fine. Also, i found a plugin in Wordpress that allows you to add script into the <head> into each singular page (Header and footer scripts by Anand Kumar). Thanks again!